# How to update entities using Xodux-DNQ

Tags: xodus, xodus-dnq

I have searched Xodus and Xodus-DNQ and I am not able to find an idiomatic way to update an entity that is already inside a Xodus database, using Xodus-DNQ. Would I have to delete that entity and created it again afterwards, or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno, you can just update the fields of the entity in a transaction. That's it.

Please, check the sample right in the README.md. In this block field `posts` of the `blog` is actually updated.

```
   xodusStore.transactional {
        // Create new post
        val post = XdPost.new {
            this.publishedAt = DateTime.now()
            this.text = args.firstOrNull() ?: "Empty post"
        }

        // Add new post to blog
        blog.posts.add(post)
    }
```

Comment: The links I knew how to do it. My doubt was with simple properties :). Thank you